# Decomposition of a rational function in partial fractions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to decompose the following rational function: $\dfrac{1}{(x^2-1)^2}$ in partial fractions (in order to untegrate it later).

I have notices that $(x^2-1)^2 = (x+1)^2(x-1)^2$

Therefore $\exists A, B, C, D$ s.t:  $\dfrac{1}{(x^2-1)^2} = \dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2(x+1)^2} = \dfrac{Ax+B}{(x+1)^2}+\dfrac{Cx+D}{(x-1)^2}$

We then have $Ax+B =\left. \dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2} \right\vert _{x=-1} \implies B-A=1/4$

Same thing for Cx+D: $Cx+D =\left. \dfrac{1}{(x+1)^2} \right\vert _{x=1} \implies C+D=1/4  $

How do I find A, B, C, D from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$1=(x-1)^2(Ax+B)+(x+1)^2(Cx+D)$$
You already have
$$B-A=C+D=\frac 14$$

Substituting $x=0$ gives
$$1=B+D$$
Substituting $x=2$ gives
$$1=2A+B+9(2C+D)$$

Solving these gives
$$A=\frac 14,\quad B=\frac 12,\quad C=-\frac 14,\quad D=\frac 12$$

Comment: I'm sorry coul you show how you solve that, it seems pretty hard I cant seem to ecpress B and D with B-A and C+D

Comment: @aribaldi: Sure. We can represent $B,C,D$ by $A$ from the first three equations, and finally use the fourth. We have $B=A+1/4$ so $D=1-B=1-(A+1/4)=-A+3/4$. Also, $C=1/4-D=1/4-(-A+3/4)=A-1/2$. Finally, from the last equation, $1=2A+(A+1/4)+18(A-1/2)+9(-A+3/4)$ from which we have $A=1/4$. You can get $B,C,D$ from this. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: substitute $x=i $ to get two additional equations one for the real part and one for the imaginary part

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

$$ \frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2} = \frac{1}{(x+1)^2(x-1)^2} = \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{(x+1)^2} + \frac{C}{x-1} + \frac{D}{(x-1)^2}$$

Try to decompose the above

Comment: When I use this technique, after having found B and D i find that A+B=1/2 where as in the answer above, but since I don't know what B is I can't go any further, how do I solve that problem?

Comment: You should obtain 3 equations in  4 variables and one equation with 2 variables.